# Pivoting results in more rows than needed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have query like this:

> ```
> `SELECT [/BIC/IORSVPTX] as Region,
> COUNTRY_ID,
> [/BIC/IOWCNTRY] as Country, 
> [/BIC/IOC_TRLNO] as Trial, 
> [/BIC/IOWQUAL] as ResourceType,
> case 
>
>     when [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%Supporter%' 
>       then 1 
>   when [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%Monitor%'
>       then 3
>   when [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%PM%'
>       then 2
>
>   end as ResourceGroup, 
> [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
> FROM 
>     (
> SELECT  [/BIC/IORSVPTX], 
> COUNTRY_ID,
> [/BIC/IOWCNTRY], 
> [/BIC/IOC_TRLNO], 
> [/BIC/IOWQUAL],    case 
>
>     when [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%Supporter%' 
>       then 1 
>   when [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%Monitor%'
>       then 3
>   when [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%PM%'
>       then 2
>
>   end as ResourceGroup, 
> left(CALMONTH,4) as StartYear,
> right(CALMONTH,2) as StartMonth,
> ((left(CALMONTH,4) - 2013) * 12) + right(CALMONTH,2) AS YearMonth,
> QUANTITY as Hours
>          FROM dbo.Actuals
>         where [/BIC/IOC_TRLNO]<>'0000' and left(CALMONTH,4)>2012 and   COUNTRY_ID='10'
> and ([/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%PM%' or [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like'%Monitor%' or [/BIC/IOWQUAL]   like '%Supporter%')
> ) up
> PIVOT (sum(Hours) FOR YearMonth IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) AS pvt;
> IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) AS pvt;`
> ```

which gives me the output with 2 rows for each ResourceType and ResourceGroup with hours for 1(Jan) and 2nd row with hours for 2(Feb) instead of 1 row

```
Region  COUNTRY_ID  Country Trial   ResourceType    ResourceGroup   1   2   3   4   5
North America   10  USA 3619     Monitor    3   158.5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
North America   10  USA 3619     Monitor    3   NULL    42  NULL    NULL    NULL
North America   10  USA 3619     PM / LTM / RTM     2   20  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
North America   10  USA 3619     PM / LTM / RTM     2   NULL    22  NULL    NULL    NULL
North America   10  USA 3619     Supporter  1   18.5    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
North America   10  USA 3619     Supporter  1   NULL    15.75   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

desired output should be like this:

```
Region  COUNTRY_ID  Country Trial   ResourceType    ResourceGroup   1   2   3   4   5
North America   10  USA 3619     Monitor    3   158.5   42  NULL    NULL    NULL
North America   10  USA 3619     PM / LTM / RTM     2   20  22  NULL    NULL    NULL
North America   10  USA 3619     Supporter  1   18.5    15.75   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things wrong with your current query.

First, you are using the `CASE` expression in the outer and the subquery. I don't fully understand why you are doing that as you created a column called `ResourceGroup`.

Second, you will get multiple rows if your subquery contains columns with distinct values and you apply the pivot.

For example in your subquery you are using:

```
left(CALMONTH,4) as StartYear,
right(CALMONTH,2) as StartMonth,
```

But you do not have these in the final select list, if you added them to the final select they will probably show distinct values which are causing the problem during the pivot grouping.

Based on your existing query I am guessing you want to use:

```
SELECT 
  [/BIC/IORSVPTX] as Region,
  COUNTRY_ID,
  [/BIC/IOWCNTRY] as Country, 
  [/BIC/IOC_TRLNO] as Trial, 
  [/BIC/IOWQUAL] as ResourceType,
  ResourceGroup, 
  [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
FROM 
(
  SELECT [/BIC/IORSVPTX], 
    COUNTRY_ID,
    [/BIC/IOWCNTRY], 
    [/BIC/IOC_TRLNO], 
    [/BIC/IOWQUAL],    
    case 
      when [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%Supporter%' then 1 
      when [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%Monitor%'   then 3
      when [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%PM%'  then 2
    end as ResourceGroup, 
    ((left(CALMONTH,4) - 2013) * 12) + right(CALMONTH,2) AS YearMonth,
    QUANTITY as Hours
  FROM dbo.Actuals
  where [/BIC/IOC_TRLNO]<>'0000' 
    and left(CALMONTH,4)>2012 
    and   COUNTRY_ID='10'
    and ([/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%PM%' 
         or [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like'%Monitor%' 
         or [/BIC/IOWQUAL] like '%Supporter%')
) up
PIVOT 
(
  sum(Hours) 
  FOR YearMonth IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) AS pvt;
```